# How to aggregate log messages in a streaming application

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, log4j, apache-flink, logback

We are using Apache flink as a stream processing framework.

We are looking for logging aggregation solution and we wonder if there is any built in connector to write logs to ES or any other sink?

Logging in Flink is by default with log4j/slf4j.

**What is your recommendation for storing logs in heavy scale?**

Thanks.

Comment: You want to collect all logs from different systems into ES? I didn't understand what you are want.

Comment: No, I have a flink job and I want to aggregate all it's logs (system and custom) into some storage that I can query after. 

This appender should deal with high scale.